# Update a calculation stated into the mysql command into a table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

The thing is this:
For all the subscribed players there is a random formula based on their skills. This formula has to be updated several times in a row with a sleep between it. The Calculation has to be a sum of the previous calculations + the new ones.
The thing is that I want to update the Calculation in my table wedstrijdresultaten, but because the calculation is in a while loop I cannot use

```
$Calculation = $row['Calculation'] + ($Skills / 35)*rand($Skills, 100);
```

This is what I thought would work, but it doesn't:

```
$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE wedstrijdresultaten  SET Calculation='".$row['Calculation'] + ($Skills / 35)*rand($Skills, 100)."'";
```

Comment: Do you mean $row['Calculation'] is to be read from the table and so on...? Would you please add the code of the while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See ["Operator Precedence" in the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). `+` and `.` have equal precedence, and are left-associative, so this:

```
"..." . a + b . "..."
```

means this:

```
(("..." . a) + b) . "..."
```

You need to use parentheses to force the addition to be performed before the concatenation:

```
$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE wedstrijdresultaten  SET Calculation='"
              . ($row['Calculation'] + ($Skills / 35)*rand($Skills, 100))
              . "'";
```

Comment: Thank you! That is what I needed! The only thing that I don't understand now is why for every player the result is the same, even though the skills are different :p

Comment: @freddddyyyyy: Well, even this change I think you'll get the same result for every player, since your `UPDATE` statement doesn't seem to have a `WHERE` clause . . .

Comment: Thanks, I just figured that out now :p Thank you for the quick help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE wedstrijdresultaten  
              SET Calculation = Calculation + " . (($Skills / 35) * rand($Skills, 100)) ;
```